# Whenever I click register it says, "your file was not found" and alerts are not showing

Tags: javascript, html

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head></head>
    
    <body>
        <form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" method="post" onsubmit="return Function()">E-mail:
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
            <br>Password:
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            <br>Repeat Password:
            <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Function() {
            
            var email = document.getElementById ("email").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
            
            var emailpattern = /^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;
              if (email.match.value(emailpattern)) {
                alert ("Email is valid!");
                return true;
                }
              else {
                alert ("Not a valid email!");
                return false;
                }
                  
            if (email.length < 5) {
            alert("Not a valid email!");
            return false;
            }
            else {
              alert("Email is valid!");
              return true;
              }
              
              if (password.length < 4) {
              alert("Password is too short");
              return false;
              }
              else {
                alert("Password is valid");
                return true;
                }
              
              if (password2.length< 4) {
                alert ("Password is too short");
                return false;
                }
              else {
                  return true;
                  }
                
              if (password != password2) {
                alert ("Passwords does not much");
                return false;
                }
              else {
                return true;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: make your form action an absolute path ie. www.mysite.com/action_page.php

Comment: Does the php file at this location /action_page.php exist?

Comment: If the /action_page.php is not in the web root, remove the leading /

Comment: Hi. So I change the action="/action_page.php" to action="#" is it okay? Though alerts are still not showing

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this one. I hope I can get your point. This is my first time making a javascript form.

Answer (score 0):

If the post action page is not in the web root, remove the leading / from action="action_page.php"

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <form name="myForm" action="action_page.php" method="post" onsubmit="return Function()">E-mail:
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
        <br>Password:
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        <br>Repeat Password:
        <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Function() {
        
        var email = document.getElementById ("email").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
        
        var emailpattern = /^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;
          if (email.match.value(emailpattern)) {
            alert ("Email is valid!");
            return true;
            }
          else {
            alert ("Not a valid email!");
            return false;
            }
              
        if (email.length < 5) {
        alert("Not a valid email!");
        return false;
        }
        else {
          alert("Email is valid!");
          return true;
          }
          
          if (password.length < 4) {
          alert("Password is too short");
          return false;
          }
          else {
            alert("Password is valid");
            return true;
            }
          
          if (password2.length< 4) {
            alert ("Password is too short");
            return false;
            }
          else {
              return true;
              }
            
          if (password != password2) {
            alert ("Passwords does not much");
            return false;
            }
          else {
            return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" method="post" onsubmit="Function()">E-mail:
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
        <br>Password:
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        <br>Repeat Password:
        <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
    <script>
        function Function() {
        
        var email = document.getElementById ("email").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
        
        var emailpattern = /^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;
          if (emailpattern.test(email)) {
            alert ("Email is valid!");
            return true;
            }
          else {
            alert ("Not a valid email!");
            return false;
            }
              
        if (email.length < 5) {
        alert("Not a valid email!");
        return false;
        }
        else {
          alert("Email is valid!");
          return true;
          }
          
          if (password.length < 4) {
          alert("Password is too short");
          return false;
          }
          else {
            alert("Password is valid");
            return true;
            }
          
          if (password2.length< 4) {
            alert ("Password is too short");
            return false;
            }
          else {
              return true;
              }
            
          if (password != password2) {
            alert ("Passwords does not much");
            return false;
            }
          else {
            return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
`
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your file was not found

You have to specify the correct path to your PHP file. If the HTML file and the PHP action page are in the same folder, try removing the slash before `action_page.php`. And your alerts are not showing, because there is an error in your javascript function. Following code works (alerts are showing, the thing with the file not being found I cannot test for you), except for that your regex must ne wrong, because it says not valid for every email I enter:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>       
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" method="post" onsubmit="return Function()">E-mail:
         <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
         <br>Password:
         <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
         <br>Repeat Password:
         <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2">
         <br>
         <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function Function() {
            
response = true;
var email = document.getElementById ("email").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
var emailpattern = "/^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/";

if (email.match(emailpattern) && email.length > 5) {
    alert ("Email is valid!");
} else {
    alert("Not a valid email!");
    return false;
}
   
if (password.length < 4) {
    alert("Password is too short");
    return false;
} else {
    alert("Password is long enough");
}

if (password != password2) {
    alert("Passwords do not match");
    return false;
} else {
    alert("Passwords do match")
}
return true;
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for helping me! But may I ask if my codes for passwords are also wrong?  Alerts for passwords are not showing

Comment: @Acel they cannot show because you are returning before they could get executed, i should have noticed that, fixed it now !